# Realm file for unit testing path permission (Xcode, Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Please forgive me if there is answered question similar to this. I tried to find any but couldn't find it

Hi guys, i am having problem with running Realm file for my unit testing

So i have moved the realm files to my project test folder

```
   SampleAppTest
      + SampleAppTest.swift
      + SampleRealm.realm
```

I can successfully located the realm file, however, when I tried to instantiate the Realm connection, it threw me an error saying

`Please use a path where your app has read-write permissions.`

```
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    if let path = bundle.path(forResource: "SampleRealm", ofType: "realm") {
        let realmLocationURL = URL(string: path)
        
        let realmVersion: UInt64 = 1
        let config = Realm.Configuration(fileURL: realmLocationURL, schemaVersion: realmVersion, migrationBlock: { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
                if (oldSchemaVersion < realmVersion) {}
            }
        )
        let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config) // throws error
    }
    else {
        print("path not found")
    }
```

`Folder access in Finder -> Get Info -> Read & Write`

So in general, where can I put a file that my app has a permission to read-write? Is there a possible way to put within the project so that other team member that clone the project can also run the test with same realm file? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Storing Realm in your [App Bundle](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/sdk/ios/advanced-guides/bundle/) makes it a read only realm so I don't think that was the intention.

The default location Realm uses for your Realm files is always a good bet - however, it won't travel with your project files.

During development, we often store our realm file with the project - that way if the project is compressed, sent or shared (or put it on dropbox) the file is always available and is read/write. Here's some code to do that:

```
func gGetRealm() -> Realm? {
    do {
        let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: #file)
        let projectSubUrl = fileUrl.deletingLastPathComponent() //the project files folder
        let projectUrl = projectSubUrl.deletingLastPathComponent() //the project folder
        let realmURL = projectUrl.appendingPathComponent("default.realm")

        var config = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration
        config.fileURL = realmURL
        let realm = try Realm.init(configuration: config)
        return realm

    } catch let error as NSError { //just throw the error to the console
        print("Error!")
        print("  " + error.localizedDescription)
        let err = error.code
        print(err)
        let t = type(of: err)
        print(t)
        return nil
    }
}
```

This is global function to get the Realm stored within the project file - use is

```
guard let realm = gGetRealm() else { return }
let results = realm.objects(MyObject.self)
```